# Problem resolving paths with vite and tinymce

Tags: tinymce, vite, tinymce-6

I want to import the tinymce silver theme like:

`import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme.min.js';`

When I do so the resolved path looks like:

`http://localhost:3000/einnahmen/angebote//skins/ui/oxide/skin.shadowdom.min.css`

but it should look like:

`http://localhost:3000/vite-dev/@fs/app/node_modules/tinymce/skins/ui/oxide/skin.min.css`.

Somehow the `baseURL` inside `theme.min.js` is replaced by the wrong path. Setting an alias to the base_url prop solves the issue but seems kinda hacky to me and not that well suited for production.

`base_url: '/vite-dev/@fs/app/node_modules/tinymce/'`